RN Fetch blob for android 14
RN Fetch blob doesn't work for android 14
When I downloaded the file, the file was downloaded but the app crashed with the error:
one of receiver_exported or receiver_not_exported should be specified in android 14 when receiving call after upgrading react native 0.73 react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep#780
Also, the downloaded file doesn't open, says, 'Can't open file'
useEffect(() => {
    setIsInvoiceDownloading(true);
    if (invoiceResponse.error && invoiceResponse.called) {
      console.log("Error in invoiceResponse")
      setIsInvoiceDownloading(false);
      firebase
        .analytics()
        .logEvent('ApiErrorMessage', { API: 'INVOICE_DOWNLOAD' });
      Snackbar.show({
        text: 'Could not fetch invoice. Please try again.',
        duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT,
      });
    } else if (invoiceResponse.data) {
      console.log("Success in invoiceResponse ", invoiceResponse)
      const dirToSave = Platform.select({
        ios: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir,
        android: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir,
      });
      console.log("dirToSave invoiceResponse", dirToSave);
      RNFetchBlob.config({
        fileCache: true,
        path: `${dirToSave}/ows-booking-invoice-${invoiceResponse.variables?.orderId}.pdf`,
        addAndroidDownloads: {
          useDownloadManager: true,
          notification: true,
          path: `${dirToSave}/ows-booking-invoice-${invoiceResponse.variables?.orderId}.pdf`,
        },
      })
        .fetch('GET', invoiceResponse.data.getInvoicePdfByBookingId)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("Fetch successful, response ", res);
          setIsInvoiceDownloading(false);
          if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(res.data);
          } else {
            console.log("File downloaded ");
            Snackbar.show({
              text: 'File Downloaded.',
              duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT,
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Fetch failed, error: ", err);
          firebase
            .analytics()
            .logEvent('ApiErrorMessage', { API: 'INVOICE_DOWNLOAD' });
          setIsInvoiceDownloading(false);
          Snackbar.show({
            text: 'Could not download invoice. Please try again.',
            duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT,
          });
        });
    }
  }, [invoiceResponse]);

